# New to IRC specifically BitchX, what is the best way to remain anonymous

Tags: anonymity, irc

when getting a list of users in a channel I can see all of my personal details. First question is this what everyone else sees, and second how can I make sure my full name is never visible.

Comment: Just don't enter your name anywhere in the configuration or in anything you write and then it will not show up.

Comment: I didn't add it anywhere nor did I type it, however in a channel when I /whois, my full name is right there along with a few other users (First name Last Name). Other users have anon names or phrases. I don't know how to revise mine nor where it is pulling from.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is known about your environment but maybe the name is given somewhere in the OS and BitchX is retrieving it from there. To set your own name follow the [documentation](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/BitchX/doc/entire-faq.html): *"... How do I change my default irc nickname and username? --
These are set by environment variables, the four most important variables
are IRCNICK, IRCNAME, USER and HOME. ..."*. But this question is more about using BitchX and not actually a security question. Note that anonymous is not the same as hiding your name only.

Comment: thank you, and yes I do agree this is only a single step within being anon, yet a key step. As BitchX is merely a fork from ircII, it is more about where my data gets pulled into the client and less about BitchX. I will check out the documentation to see if I can find the hidden jewel. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally answered my own question:

Using *nix in your local directory if the file .bitchxrc does not currently exist then go ahead and create it

`touch .bitchxrc`

then inside that add your irc commands for these 2 environment variables

```
/ircname Phrase you would like or name
/ircuser username
```

save file
relaunch bitchx
type /whois

bam -> you're no longer showing your personal info